# How to implement Spring Oauth2 Resource owner password credentials flow correct?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Assume we have authorization server + resource server, also a mobile app. All applications are developed by same company (e.g all google services + official mobile apps).

In my understanding, mobile app should use Oauth2 resource owner password credentials flow, Am I correct? [This is an article](https://stormpath.com/blog/what-the-heck-is-oauth) supports my understanding. According to [Oauth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3) its seems like not the correct approach. So what would be the correct approach? Is it the [authorization code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1) grant flow? In that case how one should cope with redirection? (there are ways but what is the best way of not leaving the app?)

Also I need to use native login screen in mobile app where resource owner need to type username/password. Could that be done via authorization code flow? how?

If I am correct about resource owner credentials flow, how we can implement that in spring without client secret embedding in the app?

Below is the required way of getting token via resource owner password credentials in spring.

```
curl -X POST --user 'trusted-client:client-secret' -d 'grant_type=password&username=test&password=123' http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

Here we need to have client secret in the app (which is not secure), will [this approach](https://gist.github.com/aeisele/2845397) work? Assume later on we may have different client, how custom authentication provider distinguish those two? Any answer would be great. Thanks.

Comment: If both server & client app belong to same company, its better to use Resource owner client credential flow, where you can directly get username & password and sent it to server. If the client app is provided by any third party, then you should use implicit or authorization code flows

Comment: Later if you have more than 1 clients, server will distinguish them on the basis of their ids(which should be stored in server database)

Comment: @Afridi Thanks for the comments. Do you mind giving an example on how to distinguishing part can be done? I am having trouble to implement CustomAuthenticationProvider which can pick correct client id based on the request (which comes from particular client).

Comment: Its client responsibility to send both client id and secret to server. After receiving, server will load given client using client id from database and validate its secret/roles/authorities(which are done automatically by Spring OAuth) etc. Just like 'username' and 'password' are used to identify & validate a user, similarly 'client id' and 'secret' are used to identify & validate a client app.